# Can Random.nextDouble() ever return the inclusive value?

Tags: java, random

I was playing around with the [`Random` class's `nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble) method as shown below. I expected `nextDouble()` to return a pseudorandom `double` value on the interval [-50.0, 50.0), however, after running the loop 1 billion times the output came out to `maximum: 49.99999995014588 minimum: -49.99999991024878`. I ran the loop without my manipulations of the output interval, and I got `maximum: 0.9999999998979311 minimum: 0.0`. I find this strange, because all I have done to the `0.0` that was returned is multiply it by 100.0 and subtract 50.0 from it. Why does this code snippet below never return exactly -50.0?

EDIT: Just for fun I ran the loop another 500 million times, and the output is now: `maximum: 49.99999994222232 minimum: -49.999999996750944`.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class randomTest{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double max = 0;
    double min = 0;
    Random math = new Random();
    for(int a = 0; a < 1000000000; a++) {
        double rand = math.nextDouble() * 100.0 - (100.0 / 2.0);
        max = Math.max(max, rand);
        min = Math.min(min, rand);
    }
    System.out.println("maximum: " + max + " minimum: " + min);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextDouble()` works by first generating a random `long`, i.e. an integer spread evenly between the numbers -2<sup>63</sup> and 2<sup>63</sup>-1.  If you generate one billion numbers, you are still generating only 10<sup>9</sup>/2<sup>64</sup> = 5.421 x 10<sup>-11</sup> of the possibilities, a tiny fraction.  Thus the odds that any particular number will be generated are extremely tiny.

Even accounting for rounding, the chance is still small.  Note that your output contains 16 significant digits, which means that there are somewhere between 10<sup>15</sup> and 10<sup>16</sup> possible sequences of decimal digits you can generate.  If you only generate 10<sup>9</sup> of those, the probability of generating any particular number is 10<sup>-7</sup>.

Comment: That doesn't affect my answer any.

Comment: I didnt think so. just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 7):

The javadoc clearly states that the upper bound on `nextDouble()` is *exclusive* not inclusive.  That means that `1.0` will not be returned.

According to the javadoc, `0.0` will be returned .... with a probability of approximately 1 in 2<sup>54</sup>.  (That is one time in  18,014,398,509,481,984.)

(It boils down to determining whether two successive calls to `next(27)` will return zero.  That is possible, if you examine the specification for the LCNG used by `next(int)`.)

---

So, your code doesn't hit `50.0` because it can't.  It should be able to hit `-50.0`  but you would probably need to run it in the order of 1.0E19 times for that to happen.  You only ran it 5.0E8 times.

Comment: @Adrian If lower bound is expected then you'd get -50.0  with your manipulation, not 50.0

Comment: @Saravana yea, i just realized I asked why it doesnt hit 50.0 instead of asking why it doesnt hit -50.0. Whoops.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from oracle docs:

> public double nextDouble() Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly
>   distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number
>   generator's sequence. The general contract of nextDouble is that one
>   double value, chosen (approximately) uniformly from the range **0.0d
>   (inclusive) to *1.0d (exclusive*)**, is pseudorandomly generated and
>   returned.
>
> The method nextDouble is implemented by class Random as if by:

```
public double nextDouble() {    return (((long)next(26) << 27) +
> next(27))
>      / (double)(1L << 53);  }
```

The hedge "approximately" is used in the foregoing description only because the next method is only

> approximately an unbiased source of independently chosen bits. If it
>   were a perfect source of randomly chosen bits, then the algorithm
>   shown would choose double values from the stated range with perfect
>   uniformity.
>
> [In early versions of Java, the result was incorrectly calculated as:

```
return (((long)next(27) << 27) + next(27))
>      / (double)(1L << 54);
```

This might seem to be equivalent, if not better, but in fact it introduced a large nonuniformity because of the

> bias in the rounding of floating-point numbers: it was three times as
>   likely that the low-order bit of the significand would be 0 than that
>   it would be 1! This nonuniformity probably doesn't matter much in
>   practice, but we strive for perfection.]

So its clear the the max value isn't included when generating the number,

Comment: Nice explanation with reference to the docs, but I am not asking why the upper bound is not returned.

Comment: @Adrian, i thought you wanted to know why doesnt it hit exact 50 right ?

Comment: crap. i just noticed i forgot the negative in front of 50.0. Your answer is correct for the question that I had previously before I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Implement it yourself. Something work for me:

```
public double nextDoubleInclusive()
{
    return myRandom.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) / (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

notice that you probably didn't get 0.0 when running without the offset.
your "min" starts with 0.0.

with a little change to your code (min = 1) you can see that you aren't getting 0.0 (you could, not the odds are against you).

```
    double max = 0;
    double min = 1;
    Random math = new Random();
    for(int a = 0; a < 1000000000; a++) {
        double rand = math.nextDouble();
        max = Math.max(max, rand);
        min = Math.min(min, rand);
    }
    System.out.println("maximum: " + max + " minimum: " + min);
```

maximum: 0.9999999989149039 minimum: 4.5566594941703897E-10